# Where can I find a good source code for benchmarking a certain compiler?

Tags: c++

I want to determine which compiler is better on 2 different platforms. First, I want to know whether sunCC or GCC generates fastest code in a Solaris system. Then, I'd like to know whether  aCC or GCC generates fastest code in a HP/UX system. 
Thanks.

Comment: You really need to test it with _your_ code.  Different compilers may perform better than others given different code.

Comment: The exact combination of optimization-related flags matters too.  The best settings will vary by application.

Answer (score 3):

While there may be a universal compiler that is better than another... I think it would usually boil down to your specific application.  Take a small part of your code the core loop that you want to be fast.. make a simple 10 line benchmark around it... and try your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Test which one goes faster using `time.h` to make timers in a various locations of your program and compare the results you get with the different compilers. Like Jame McNellis said:

> You really need to test it with your code. Different compilers may perform better than others given different code.